# Can somebody help me on a simple chain rule differentiation problem [As level]

Tags: functions, derivatives

It's my first time using this forums so please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong and pardon for my stupid question.

So I believe that when you differentiate $2$ functions e.g $y = f(g(x))$, you would differentiate the inner one first, then the outer one with the inner function acting as $x$ like this: 
$$y = g'(x) \cdot f'(g(x))$$

However, I'm struggling to see where the definition of a function is.

Let me illustrate:

So in my book it says.

$$y = 3\sin(2x)$$

Is this the same as f(g(y(x)))
Where

$$f(x) = 3x$$

$$g(x) = \sin{x}$$

$$y(x) = 2x$$

In this case, It would differentiate to obtain: 
$$y'(x) \cdot g'(y(x)) \cdot f'(g(y(x)))$$

which would be $2 \cdot \cos{2x} \cdot 3(\sin{2x})$

However, this is wrong. The answer is $6\cos{2x}$

Could somebody please explain why or where I went wrong.

It seems like that $f(x)$ is not considered as a function. But then I think about $f(x) = 3x$  and it seems to me to be like a function by itself (which is take a number and multiply it by $3$) Anyways, I'm not very sure as to how to approach this and make sure I don't get this wrong again

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: I edited your question. I hope it's all ok and more clear

Comment: Sorry, but how did you do that?

Comment: The edition or the math style in the formulas

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Can you clarify what you mean when you say that it seems like $f(x)$ is not really a function - what is leading you to think that?

Comment: Because f(x) is basically the 3 in front of the sin(2x) which seems like a number instead of a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f(x)=3x$$
$$g(x)=\sin{x}$$
$$h(x)=2x$$

Composing:
$$f(g(h(x))=3\sin{2x}$$

$$(f(g(h(x)))'=f'(g(h(x))(g(h(x)))'=f'(g(h(x))g'(h(x))h'(x)$$
$$f'(g(h(x))=3$$
$$g'(h(x))=\cos{2x}$$
$$h'(x)=2$$

Then:

$$(f(g(h(x)))'=6\cos{2x}$$

Comment: Confirming here....So the problem was that when I differentiated f'(x) , I got 3x when It should have been 3

Comment: @Tomato721 yes.